# Failed to load resource:server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to send a call using ajax but I got this error.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The error is in **jquery.min.js** file

```
    send    @   jquery.min.js:4
    ajax    @   jquery.min.js:4
    (anonymous) @   upload_excel:534
    dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
    r.handle    @   jquery.min.js:3


try {
    h.send(b.hasContent && b.data || null)
} catch (i) {
    if (c) throw i
}
}, abort: function() {
c && c()
}
}: void 0
}), n.ajaxSetup({
    accepts: {
        script: "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
    },
    contents: {
        script: /\b(?:java|ecma)script\b/
    },
    converters: {
        "text script": function(a) {
            return n.globalEval(a), a
        }
    }
}), n.ajaxPrefilter("script", function(a) {
    void 0 === a.cache && (a.cache = !1), a.crossDomain && (a.type = "GET")
}), n.ajaxTransport("script", function(a) {
    if (a.crossDomain) {
        var b, c;
        return {
            send: function(e, f) {
                b = n("<script>").prop({
                    charset: a.scriptCharset,
                    src: a.url
                }).on("load error", c = function(a) {
                    b.remove(), c = null, a && f("error" === a.type ? 404 : 200, a.type)
                }), d.head.appendChild(b[0])
            },
            abort: function() {
                c && c()
            }
        }
    }
});
var Jb = [],
    Kb = /(=)\?(?=&|$)|\?\?/;
n.ajaxSetup({
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: function() {
        var a = Jb.pop() || n.expando + "_" + kb++;
        return this[a] = !0, a
    }
}), n.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp", function(b, c, d) {
    var e, f, g, h = b.jsonp !== !1 && (Kb.test(b.url) ? "url" : "string" == typeof b.data && 0 === (b.contentType || "").indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") && Kb.test(b.data) && "data");
    return h || "jsonp" === b.dataTypes[0] ? (e = b.jsonpCallback = n.isFunction(b.jsonpCallback) ? b.jsonpCallback() : b.jsonpCallback, h ? b[h] = b[h].replace(Kb, "$1" + e) : b.jsonp !== !1 && (b.url += (lb.test(b.url) ? "&" : "?") + b.jsonp + "=" + e), b.converters["script json"] = function() {
        return g || n.error(e + " was not called"), g[0]
    }, b.dataTypes[0] = "json", f = a[e], a[e] = function() {
        g = arguments
    }, d.always(function() {
        void 0 === f ? n(a).removeProp(e) : a[e] = f, b[e] && (b.jsonpCallback = c.jsonpCallback, Jb.push(e)), g && n.isFunction(f) && f(g[0]), g = f = void 0
    }), "script") : void 0
}), n.parseHTML = function(a, b, c) {
    if (!a || "string" != typeof a) return null;
    "boolean" == typeof b && (c = b, b = !1), b = b || d;
    var e = x.exec(a),
        f = !c && [];
    return e ? [b.createElement(e[1])] : (e = ca([a], b, f), f && f.length && n(f).remove(), n.merge([], e.childNodes))
};
var Lb = n.fn.load;
n.fn.load = function(a, b, c) {
    if ("string" != typeof a && Lb) return Lb.apply(this, arguments);
    var d, e, f, g = this,
        h = a.indexOf(" ");
    return h > -1 && (d = n.trim(a.slice(h)), a = a.slice(0, h)), n.isFunction(b) ? (c = b, b = void 0) : b && "object" == typeof b && (e = "POST"), g.length > 0 && n.ajax({
        url: a,
        type: e || "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data: b
    }).done(function(a) {
        f = arguments, g.html(d ? n("<div>").append(n.parseHTML(a)).find(d) : a)
    }).always(c && function(a, b) {
        g.each(function() {
            c.apply(this, f || [a.responseText, b, a])
        })
    }), this
}, n.each(["ajaxStart", "ajaxStop", "ajaxComplete", "ajaxError", "ajaxSuccess", "ajaxSend"], function(a, b) {
    n.fn[b] = function(a) {
        return this.on(b, a)
    }
}), n.expr.filters.animated = function(a) {
    return n.grep(n.timers, function(b) {
        return a === b.elem
    }).length
};

function Mb(a) {
    return n.isWindow(a) ? a : 9 === a.nodeType && a.defaultView
}
n.offset = {
    setOffset: function(a, b, c) {
        var d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k = n.css(a, "position"),
            l = n(a),
            m = {};
        "static" === k && (a.style.position = "relative"), h = l.offset(), f = n.css(a, "top"), i = n.css(a, "left"), j = ("absolute" === k || "fixed" === k) && (f + i).indexOf("auto") > -1, j ? (d = l.position(), g = d.top, e = d.left) : (g = parseFloat(f) || 0, e = parseFloat(i) || 0), n.isFunction(b) && (b = b.call(a, c, n.extend({}, h))), null != b.top && (m.top = b.top - h.top + g), null != b.left && (m.left = b.left - h.left + e), "using" in b ? b.using.call(a, m) : l.css(m)
    }
}, n.fn.extend({
    offset: function(a) {
        if (arguments.length) return void 0 === a ? this : this.each(function(b) {
            n.offset.setOffset(this, a, b)
        });
        var b, c, d = this[0],
            e = {
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            },
            f = d && d.ownerDocument;
        if (f) return b = f.documentElement, n.contains(b, d) ? (e = d.getBoundingClientRect(), c = Mb(f), {
            top: e.top + c.pageYOffset - b.clientTop,
            left: e.left + c.pageXOffset - b.clientLeft
        }) : e
    },
    position: function() {
        if (this[0]) {
            var a, b, c = this[0],
                d = {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                };
            return "fixed" === n.css(c, "position") ? b = c.getBoundingClientRect() : (a = this.offsetParent(), b = this.offset(), n.nodeName(a[0], "html") || (d = a.offset()), d.top += n.css(a[0], "borderTopWidth", !0), d.left += n.css(a[0], "borderLeftWidth", !0)), {
                top: b.top - d.top - n.css(c, "marginTop", !0),
                left: b.left - d.left - n.css(c, "marginLeft", !0)
            }
        }
    },
    offsetParent: function() {
        return this.map(function() {
            var a = this.offsetParent;
            while (a && "static" === n.css(a, "position")) a = a.offsetParent;
            return a || Ea
        })
    }
}), n.each({
    scrollLeft: "pageXOffset",
    scrollTop: "pageYOffset"
}, function(a, b) {
    var c = "pageYOffset" === b;
    n.fn[a] = function(d) {
        return K(this, function(a, d, e) {
            var f = Mb(a);
            return void 0 === e ? f ? f[b] : a[d] : void(f ? f.scrollTo(c ? f.pageXOffset : e, c ? e : f.pageYOffset) : a[d] = e)
        }, a, d, arguments.length)
    }
}), n.each(["top", "left"], function(a, b) {
    n.cssHooks[b] = Ga(l.pixelPosition, function(a, c) {
        return c ? (c = Fa(a, b), Ba.test(c) ? n(a).position()[b] + "px" : c) : void 0
    })
}), n.each({
    Height: "height",
    Width: "width"
}, function(a, b) {
    n.each({
        padding: "inner" + a,
        content: b,
        "": "outer" + a
    }, function(c, d) {
        n.fn[d] = function(d, e) {
            var f = arguments.length && (c || "boolean" != typeof d),
                g = c || (d === !0 || e === !0 ? "margin" : "border");
            return K(this, function(b, c, d) {
                var e;
                return n.isWindow(b) ? b.document.documentElement["client" + a] : 9 === b.nodeType ? (e = b.documentElement, Math.max(b.body["scroll" + a], e["scroll" + a], b.body["offset" + a], e["offset" + a], e["client" + a])) : void 0 === d ? n.css(b, c, g) : n.style(b, c, d, g)
            }, b, f ? d : void 0, f, null)
        }
    })
}), n.fn.extend({
    bind: function(a, b, c) {
        return this.on(a, null, b, c)
    },
    unbind: function(a, b) {
        return this.off(a, null, b)
    },
    delegate: function(a, b, c, d) {
        return this.on(b, a, c, d)
    },
    undelegate: function(a, b, c) {
        return 1 === arguments.length ? this.off(a, "**") : this.off(b, a || "**", c)
    },
    size: function() {
        return this.length
    }
}), n.fn.andSelf = n.fn.addBack, "function" == typeof define && define.amd && define("jquery", [], function() {
    return n
});
var Nb = a.jQuery,
    Ob = a.$;
return n.noConflict = function(b) {
return a.$ === n && (a.$ = Ob), b && a.jQuery === n && (a.jQuery = Nb), n
}, b || (a.jQuery = a.$ = n), n
});
```

When I checked the error in phpmyadmin, I got this error. Any Ideas how I can solve it.

```
{
    "pma_version": "4.4.15.2",
    "browser_name": "CHROME",
    "browser_version": "79.0.3945.79",
    "user_os": "Win",
    "server_software": "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36",
    "locale": "en",
    "configuration_storage": "enabled",
    "php_version": "5.6.40",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "Cannot read property '0' of null",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": 235,
                "func": "",
                "context": [
                    "                lastException = null;",
                    "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                    "            }",
                    "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                    "",
                    "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                    "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                    "    return report;"
                ],
                "column": "",
                "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "getFieldValidators",
                "line": 302,
                "column": "40",
                "context": [
                    " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                    " */",
                    "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                    "{",
                    "    // look for field bound validator",
                    "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                    "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                    "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    // look for registered validators"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "validate_field",
                "line": 418,
                "column": "21",
                "context": [
                    "{",
                    "    var args, result;",
                    "    var $field = $(field);",
                    "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                    "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                    "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                    "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                    "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                    "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                    "        } else {",
                    "            args = [];"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 511,
                "column": "13",
                "context": [
                    "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                    "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                    "        // run all field validators",
                    "        var errors = {};",
                    "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                    "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                    "        }",
                    "        // run all fieldset validators",
                    "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                    "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                    "        });"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
                "line": 279,
                "column": "33",
                "context": [
                    "     */",
                    "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                    "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                    "            var new_func = function () {",
                    "                try {",
                    "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                    "                } catch (x) {",
                    "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                    "                }",
                    "            };",
                    "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                ],
                "filename": "error_report.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.dispatch",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "8436",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
                "line": 374,
                "column": "19",
                "context": [
                    "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                    "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                    "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                    "\t\treturn;",
                    "\t}",
                    "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                    "};",
                    "",
                    "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                    "var touchHooks = ",
                    "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.r.handle",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "5139",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Object.trigger",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "7537",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "15404",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Function.each",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "2973",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36",
        "incomplete": "false",
        "partial": "true",
        "uri": "sql.php?target="
    },
    "script_name": "sql.php",
    "microhistory": {
        "current_index": "0"
    }
}
```

Also, I have this notification in my PHPMyAdmin is it possible this could be the cause?

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.69 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.57. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Please do not post the minified javascript, its unreadable. A starting point to solving the issue is to look at line 235 of the file. This may alos be helpful : https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/

Comment: Please expand your javascript in a way so it is more readable, so you can trace it to see where the problem occurs.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I checked the error in phpmyadmin"? It sounds to me like you tried to run an SQL query by jQuery that failed, so you tried the SQL query through phpMyadmin — but what is that query?